# How to create a Map using hibernate with a join or query (Title is not enough to explain it)

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

What I am trying to do is get Hibernate to produce a Map for me based on either a Join or a select (whichever will work). That part is statically known and thus I shouldn't have to go out to the DB to make a separate select.

From that Map I want to then use a runtime key to get the final value. See tables and code below

The business case: We want to be able to produce different content for various alerts in our system given: Medium (email/sms), Event (what happened) and eventually user input. 
It doesn't make sense to send a graphical chart to an SMS destination but would be great for email (for example) given the same event. We can leverage existing code for applying XSLT style sheets and that's what we are ultimately after.

The annotations surrounding this are confusing as hell and I confess to perhaps thinking entirely wrong about the problem. I am looking for some education and a solution.

```
CREATE TABLE AlertProfile(
  AlertProfileID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  Description VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `Type` enum('EMAIL','SMS','COMPOSITE') NOT NULL,
  Destination VARCHAR(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (AlertProfileID)
)
```

'JOIN' on Type

```
CREATE TABLE EventTemplates(
  EventTemplateID BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  EventName VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  `Type` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  TemplateXSLT MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (EventTemplateID)
)
```

There are some missing tables with AlertProfiles that I don't think are relevant to the discussion.

Now that code I would **LIKE** to work:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("EMAIL")
public class EmailAlertProfile extends AlertProfile<String>  {


    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Destination")
    private String emailAddress;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKey(name = "Type")
    private Map<String, EventTemplate> nameToTemplate = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return Type.EMAIL;
    }

    @Override
    public void sendAlert(EventMessage event) {
        // code here to work. Use the event type to select from 
        // all available email templates
        String template = eventTemplates.get(event.getEventType());
        String content = event.applyStyleSheet(new Source(template))
        VWMessage vw = new VWMessage("no-reply@company.com",emailAddress,event.getSubject(),);
        event.setRecipient(emailAddress);
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = StaticContext.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        Queue queue = (Queue) StaticContext.getBean("emailQueue");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, event);

    }
}
```